# access non-properties from inside the same class in objective-c (copy constructor)

Tags: objective-c

In C++ you can access the private members of another object if it is of the same type and I often do this in the copy constructor. Is there a way to do this in objective-c?

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
{
   NSObject * object;
}
// in the .m
-(id) initWithObject:(SomeClass*) sc
{
  self = [super init];
  object = sc.object; // possible without a property? 
  return self;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, use pointer notation:

```
self->object = other->object;
```

Just be sure that if not using ARC, that you `-retain` / `-copy` any variables needed!